# Why does Monodevelop ask me for a ssh key password when it is registered in ssh-agent

Tags: git, github, monodevelop

I can commit it fine using the command line and monodevelop has no issue with the public repo but when i try to push it to github it keeps asking me for the password to idrsa, I have tried using ssh-add to verify the key and it verifys fine.

Comment: What platform are you running on?  Where is the "public repo" located?  If you enter the correct password for the key does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- you can push from the command line without being asked for your password, and
- you're not using Windows, then

Monodevelop probably does not have the correct value of the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.  Try starting Monodevelop from the command prompt so that it will inherit the same environment variables used by the `git` command.

Comment: Tried that and it still does not work, I am using a git version of mono-develop if that maters

Answer (score 0):

I see this too.  Did you ever resolve it?  Even if you set up passwordless key auth, this fails.  It seems like a bug in the way Monodevelop uses LibGit2Sharp.  Trying to build a workaround.  Strange this has been an issue for so long.  I had better luck in 5.9 before 5.10.  Maybe now that Microsoft is buying it things will improve.